# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript

```js
interface A {
  name?: string
  age: number
}

var a: A = {
  name: '',
  age: 23
}

var result:A = (Object.keys(a) as Array<keyof A>).reduce((prev, key) => {
  if (a[key] || a[key] === 0) {
    prev[key] = a[key] // this reported a error about `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'`
  }
  return prev
}, {} as A)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

above is reproduce code.

I found that the code works under typescript@~3.4.0,but does not compileunder typescript@^3.5.0, and I checked the update log between 3.4 and 3.5,but I did not find any references about this.

So I guess if it is because `index signature` is not set, then:

```
interface A {
  name?: string
  age: number
  [K:string]:any <-- add this line
}

var a: A = {
  name: '',
  age: 23
}

var result:A = (Object.keys(a) as Array<keyof A>).reduce((prev, key/* validation lost */) => {
  if (a[key] || a[key] === 0) {
    prev[key] = a[key]
  }
  return prev
}, {} as A)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

The previous error disappeared, but the type of `key` that was the parameter in the `reduce` callback became `string|number`, causing the type validation of the key to be lost.

Is this the normal behavior?

if yes, I wonder that how to solve `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'`,and keep the type check for the `key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TS 3.5 there actually happened a breaking change with the PR [Improve soundness of indexed access types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769):

> When an indexed access T[K] occurs on the source side of a type relationship, it resolves to a union type of the properties selected by T[K], but when it occurs on the target side of a type relationship, it now resolves to an intersection type of the properties selected by T[K]. Previously, the target side would resolve to a union type as well, which is unsound.

Carried over to your example, `prev[key] = a[key]` now emits an error, because `key` has the union type `"name" | "age"` and `prev[key]` (the target side of the assignment) resolves to an intersection type of all selected properties: `A["name"] & A["age"]`, which is `string & number` or in other words `never` (with `prev` of type `A`).

The thought behind this inferred intersection for `prev[key]` is to ensure that all possible keys `"name" | "age"` of `prev` can be safely written to. If the run-time value of `key` is `age`, it would be an error to write a `string` (the expected property type of `name`) to it. At compile time with type `keyof A`, we don't know, what the exact value of `key` is, so the changes in the PR enforce safer types.

The solution is to introduce generic type parameters for the object (`prev`) and/or property name(`key`). Some examples are given [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-500913385), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-503643456) by the maintainers. I am not sure about your use case, but for example you could rewrite the code like this:

```
const result: A = (Object.keys(a) as Array<keyof A>).reduce(
  <K extends keyof A>(prev: A, key: K) => {
    // t[key] === 0 would only work for numbers
    if (a[key] /* || t[key] === 0 */) {
      prev[key] = a[key]
    }
    return prev
  }, {} as A)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=14&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkhwC2EA-AFzIDOYUoA5rvnPRJSAK5EBG0uAvrlwIA9iBrI4ldAF5MTAsTbIA5CoA0ClsoBMAZgFCco8WGRQIVDgBsw05HIAUAeW4ArCAjAA6ANYQATypHOABKSSo0KCg4AIAefwCRGDQAPlDvCwATDiRHBTiAaWQIAA9IECzIxOS0xwAHCwA3aXVkRMpC8JlU+Tx8ZAB6QeQwAG1EgF0HGTkABmQAdxEbLOQxawClkShfZBgdgi5eKCoFfGAUkInA6cGAKmQAHyfRm4Dp2fnke8Hw7H6A2QjQgTXen0k4POyEEgPMEDAHCgIGBzQU-DaGH4ETQoSMJioImsEG81hE9EcACkAMrOABy3hodBA9EuAUcFistlCoSAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I went through the issue and  learned to refer to generic types to prevent types on both sides of the equation from resolving to the corresponding union or intersection types when statically checked.But in this case, how do the types on both sides of the equality sign translate in typescript？

Comment: Given `prev: T` with constraint `<T extends object>` and `key` with type `keyof T`, the type of `prev[key]` in an assignment `prev[key] = ...` would be just resolved to `T[keyof T]` and not the intersection of all possible property values (like with non generic types), as the shape of `T` is unknown and type resolution deferred here. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdE4AjAK02gD4AKABwCdMA3ALkTQEpEBvALAAoRIggIiURAGtMATxIBeRAHlK1KADpZCxi1a8AhiTo64wLtwDaAXQDcw0cDhNEdcWEkz5pCzqK8giKiiMxsVjo2iMqasYgA9PGIUHIMmFwR8uZcUThp0JgEjogAvsJlQkA)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.Based on your last comment, `a[key]` in a assignment `prev[key] = a[key]` will also be translated to `T[keyof T]` , assume type of  `a` same as type of `prev`  so it can match.Is that right?

Comment: Yes! Here is what you can do: [Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqA8AVRVADylTABMBnROAIwCtVoA+ACigEYAuRPAGkRQATDzwBKRAG8AsAChEiCAkpRBHANKoAntQC8iAPIMmUAHQBrbZXYcJAQ2qtLWuMF5iA2gF0A3HIXAcOiIrEpgKojONG6cmjoSMvIKah7OXoj6wqna6YgA9HmCWgAOqLzZLm546cSl0Kjk-ogAvnLNQA). [This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-503643456) is another example of your mentioned case.