# Type 'fooType[K]' is not assignable to type 'barType[K]' when K is a shared property of both

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the below piece of code, I am trying to, for every property of `foo`, check if that property in `bar` is `nullish`, if so, overwrite that property of `bar` with the property from `foo`.

```js
type fooType = {
  a?: string
  b?: number
}

type barType = fooType & {
  c: string
}

const foo: fooType = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 5,
}

const bar: barType = {
  a: 'greetings',
  b: undefined,
  c: 'not in foo',
}

const fooKeys = Object.keys(foo) as Array<keyof typeof foo>
fooKeys.forEach((k) => {
  bar[k] ??= foo[k]
})
```

I get the error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`

When I hover over `k` it says `k: "a" | "b"` so I guess the problem is that typescript is interpreting this as potentially there could be a situation where this code is trying `bar[a] ??= foo[b]`... is this the case?

I tried to implement a solution similar to this one:
[Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173087/type-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-never)

```js
fooKeys.forEach(<K extends keyof typeof foo>(k: K) => {
  bar[k] ??= foo[k]
})
```

But then I get the error

```js
Type 'fooType[K]' is not assignable to type 'barType[K]'.
  Type 'fooType' is not assignable to type 'barType'.
    Property 'c' is missing in type 'fooType' but required in type '{ c: string; }'.
```

How can I fix this?

[Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4nLaN)

Comment: You can fix it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8xjpw); TS only allows generic property assignment `y[k] = x[k]` when either `x[k]` is of the intersection of all known property types of `y`, or if `y` and `x` are of *identical* types.  Otherwise it will balk, even in cases like this where the assignment is definitely safe.  If that fully addresses your question I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: I think this solves my issue except 1) How can _bar have the c property when it is FooType 2)  How do I in the end obtain a `bar` which has `BarType` (  `_bar` has `FooType` and `bar` still does not have all the parameters

Comment: 1) Types in TypeScript are open, not closed; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61845432/2887218 for more info 2) `bar` starts off as `BarType` so it is always a `BarType`; the `_bar` variable refers to the same object as `bar` so both of them have all the properties at the end.  Maybe I'm missing something about what you're looking for?  Let me know so I can figure out how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz 1) Makes sense 2) So basically I just need to finish with `bar = _bar as BarType` - feel free to write up the answer, I will mark it as the solution

Comment: @jcalz I was just wondering if there is a way that after this piece of code one could add a line for typescript which changes the type of  `_bar` from `FooType` to `BarType` instead of reassigning `_bar` to `bar` - then I could just use `_bar` from that point on instead,

Comment: You could write an assertion function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEBAbN) but I really do not understand why you want this.  The `_bar` variable is just a temporary widening of `bar` and you can dispose of it as soon as you're done with it.  Any change to properties `_bar` also happens to properties of `bar`; they are the same reference.  So I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use `bar` itself, which is already of type `BarType`.

Comment: @jcalz thanks so much for the help - I didnt realize that changing _bar would also change bar - feel free to put your answer, I will mark it as the solution

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're running into is a consequence of [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), an increase of strictness when doing assignments with [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that was released with TypeScript 3.5.

As you noted, generally, when one tries to assign `bar[k] = foo[k]`, the compiler is very conservative and acts as if it is `bar[k1] = foo[k2]` where `k1` and `k2` are different values of the same type... if that type might be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then the assignment will only succeed if `foo[k2]` is assignable to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all the possible types `bar[k1]` could be.

This is why the compiler complains that `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`, because the intersection of `string` and `number` is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

---

The fix is mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) on microsoft/TypeScript#30769:

> One rule we've always had is that any given type (and, by extension, any `T[K]` for identical `T` and `K`) is by definition assignable to itself, and that's the basic unsoundness we permit [when at least one of `T` and `K` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)].

In your code, `K` is generic, but the type `T` is not identical; in `bar[k] ??= foo[k];`, you have `BarType[K]` on the left and `FooType[K]` on the right.  `BarType` and `FooType` are not identical, so it fails.

But since `BarType` is a *subtype* of `FooType`, you are allowed to widen `bar` from `BarType` to `FooType` (this is most easily done by assigning to a temporary new variable):

```
const fooKeys = Object.keys(foo) as Array<keyof FooType>
fooKeys.forEach(<K extends keyof FooType>(k: K) => {
  const _bar: FooType = bar; // <-- widen
  _bar[k] ??= foo[k]; // okay
})
```

That succeeds, because `_bar` and `foo` are both of type `FooType`, and so you have `FooType[K]` on both sides of the assignment.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAKuaBeKBvAsAKClAQwH4AuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHNd8AjUqOgVwFsWIrcAX1y5QkKACECVZOPTwkKKADJMzKAGMylWoyEicGuHUpQAZgjILZaNXkJkA5AAsIAGzdxHAGnUsyAKy+OMI4uEYmwFAs0mRSMkro2PYETgxUEBDA9AzkPn5knHQAJhBm9BDFwfhaUI50cFH05gj5IQYRphZwANIQIORQ6ADyLABWEBrAAHQA1v3kABTdAJSEgwCCVFQEIAA88yBwZrAINgB8uN19A9MWVACiBBrOi3s9UBAAHsAQJYOHY6nRSQc6LWZkHprVDnOw1YymAD6MSoVjOiWi0gA3OpkdIANqzAC6UCIRHQ3UJRJxIRWQA)